# Why, when my identify a value, does it return as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var secs_time;
        var timer2;
        var arrayseq1 = [];
        var secs_up = 0;
        var timer1;
        var secs_down = 0;
        $("#pad").mousedown(function(){



            $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
            clearInterval(timer2);  

            timer1 = setInterval(function(){
                secs_down = secs_down + 1;
                $("#pad").html(secs_down);
            },1);

            arrayseq1 = arrayseq1.concat([secs_down]);



        }).mouseup(function(){



            $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
            clearInterval(timer1);

            timer2 = setInterval(function(){
                secs_up = secs_up + 1;
                $("#pad").html(secs_up);
            },1);
            arrayseq1 = arrayseq1.concat([secs_up]);
        });
        $("#pad").mouseleave(function(){
            clearInterval(timer2);

        });
        $("#done").click(function(){
            arrayseq1.splice(1, 1);
            arrayseq1.splice(0, 1);
            var counter = 0;
            var colors = ["#FF3E96", "#4169E1", "#7FFF00","#FF4500","#FF7F00", "black", "white"];
            while(counter <= arrayseq1.length){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
                    $("body").css("background-color", color);
                }, arrayseq1[counter]);

                counter++;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<div style = "height:500px;width:600px;background-color:grey;border-radius:4px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:10%;" id = "pad"></div>
<input type = "button" id = "done" value = "play">
```

Hi all.

I am making a small program, that when you press, and press of a huge grey button, it records the time its held down, and up and all put into an array (read the code to get a better understanding, its not to hard to understand). Anyway, so it records the times to the array successfully, so the array "arrayseq1" does have a list of times e.g [106,144,114,152,122,161,130,311,148,357]. The problem comes when i try and loop through each number, and use each as a delay for the flash of the background. So, the specific problem is when i substitute "arrayseq1[counter]" in the setTimeout function. For some reason i do not understand, it is undefined. Why? How can i fix this?

in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5V4Lv/
I alert the value arrayseq1[counter] the line before i use it for the setTimeout function, and as you will see, it alerts "undefined"

so you can test this out successfully, click on the grey box fastly and randomly, and then when you are down, move your mouse off the box  to stop recording. Then click play to start the flashing.

The original aim of this was for the background to flash in random colours in exact sync and beat to how you initially clicked the grey box.

Thanks!

Comment: first the loop should be `while (counter < arrayseq1.length) {` because array indexes are from `0....length-1`

Comment: As @ArunPJohny said, you have a problem in your loop condition. Moreover, I think your `setInterval(...,1)` is not reliable, it is too fast and as a result, the final animation will be executed too quickly and won't necessarily respect the input rythm. Use an higher interval and change the increment accordingly. You can refer to http://www.adequatelygood.com/Minimum-Timer-Intervals-in-JavaScript.html